# What context should I use in Android for Media Player

Tags: android, mp3, android-mediaplayer, android-context

I'm a new at app development. I'm trying to make a simple app that will play a single mp3 file by pressing a button. This is my code for the actual action:

```
private void setupPlayButton() {
    MediaPlayer playBitton = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.hello_bitches);
    playBitton.start(); 
}
```

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: You can pass the `Activity` because it implements `Context`. If you're not writing this method in an activity, where is the method? In a helper class?

Comment: also your button is called 'bitton' :D

Answer (score 1):

If you're in an `Activity` class, you can use that as the context.

```
public class YourClass extends Activity {

    private void setupPlayButton() {
        MediaPlayer playBitton = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.hello_bitches);
        playBitton.start();
    }
}
```

If not, pass a context to your method as a parameter:

```
private void setupPlayButton(Context aContext) {
    MediaPlayer playBitton = MediaPlayer.create(aContext, R.raw.hello_bitches);
    playBitton.start();
}
```